# Wrong Image, javascript url Path

Tags: laravel

I host Laravel project on xampp server. but now I run the laravel project using php artisan serve. When I run the artisan server, the url is http://localhost:8000. but my xampp server is http://localhost. The url path is wrong. The images doesn't appear and javascript and jquery don't work on my project. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

use this way to url **CSS** and **JS** files path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

and image path use

```
     <img src="{{url('/images'}}"> 
//here you have to give public path ex: in your public folder has images then use like this
```